# Glass Mapper and Microsoft DI

Tags: glass-mapper, dependency-injection

I am using Microsoft DI with Sitecore 8.2 Update 3. I have registered my Glass Items like this:

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISitecoreContext>(provider => new SitecoreContext());
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IGlassHtml>(provider => new GlassHtml(serviceProvider.GetService<ISitecoreContext>()));
serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICustomSitecoreContext>(provider => new CustomSitecoreContext(serviceProvider.GetService<IGlassHtml>()));
serviceCollection.AddScoped<ISitecoreService>(provider => new SitecoreService(Sitecore.Context.Database));
```

Most of these things are resolving. But, when I use the CustomSitecoreContext, the parameter GlassHTML is null. I can see on showservicesconfig.aspx that IGlassHtml is registered. Im thinking its maybe not registered in time to use it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing the details of your implementation on `ICustomSitecoreContext`, it looks to me like you are registering the dependencies incorrectly. While the `ISitecoreContext` needs the factory method to instantiate a `new SitecoreContext` - your other dependencies should be able to be created by the container.

E.g:

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISitecoreContext>(provider => new SitecoreContext());
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IGlassHtml, GlassHtml>();
serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICustomSitecoreContext, CustomSitecoreContext>();
serviceCollection.AddScoped<ISitecoreService>(provider => new SitecoreService(Sitecore.Context.Database));
```

If you register them like that, your container then takes care of making sure that the `IGlassHtml` object injected into your `CustomSitecoreContext` class is instantiated.

Alternatively - if you need to use the factory method, then you need to use the `provider` method from the lambda. Like this:

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IGlassHtml>(provider => new GlassHtml(provider.GetService<ISitecoreContext>()));
serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICustomSitecoreContext>(provider => new CustomSitecoreContext(provider.GetService<IGlassHtml>()));
```

Hope that helps!